# MWS get all product pricing

Tags: amazon-mws

If you use Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN method

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN.html

you get 3 offers

```
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse
xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult ASIN="B002KT3XQM" status="Success">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
        xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
        <Identifiers>
            <MarketplaceASIN>
                <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
                <ASIN>B002KT3XQM</ASIN>
            </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <LowestOfferListings>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>VeryGood</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>762</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>32.99</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>28.00</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>4.99</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>181744</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>34.27</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>34.27</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
            <LowestOfferListing>
                <Qualifiers>
                    <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
                    <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
                    <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
                    <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                    <ShippingTime>
                        <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                    </ShippingTime>
                    <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                </Qualifiers>
                <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                <SellerFeedbackCount>13213</SellerFeedbackCount>
                <Price>
                    <LandedPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>41.18</Amount>
                    </LandedPrice>
                    <ListingPrice>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>41.18</Amount>
                    </ListingPrice>
                    <Shipping>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    </Shipping>
                </Price>
                <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
            </LowestOfferListing>
        </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>60979901-82af-457b-8bdd-EXAMPLE28478</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
```

But if I visit product page:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002KT3XQM/ref=olp_page_1?ie=UTF8&f_new=true

I see 13 offers.

Is it possible get all 13 offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN` call gives you *one* result for each set of so-called "Qualifiers". Your example shows three distinct sets of such Qualifiers:

- Used-VeryGood->Merchant->True->0-2 days->90-94% for $32.99 (incl. shippng)
- New->New->Amazon->True->0-2 days->98-100% for $34.27
- New->New->Amazon->True->0-2 days->95-97%  for $41.18

What is puzzling me, is that no new "Merchant" offers were shown, when I really think they should:

- New->New->Merchant->True->0-2 days->98-100% would be a distinct fourth set of qualifiers.

What you really seem to be looking for is a different call: [GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN.html) returns up to 20 different offers for a single ASIN.